# ssl.conf SSLCipherSuite not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, openssl, apache2

I have an AWS server and have been testing it with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to determine if I'm setting things up correctly.

```
Type: Amazon Linux AMI 2 
Apache version: 2.4.39
OpenSSL: 1.0.2k-fips
```

I'm looking at the Cipher Suites in the results and it's showing a lot of 'weak' Ciphers.

I've attempted to make changes to the SSLCipherSuite within ssl.conf but nothing seems to work (as in, nothing seems to even change the Cipher Suites being listed). I've even commented out SSLCipherSuite and it doesn't affect the output of ssllabs at all!

My ssl.conf has this:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

I have always restarted Apache after each change.

I can only guess it might be pulling the cipher suites from somewhere else?

I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I can only guess it might be pulling the cipher suites from somewhere else? " No. As for configuration, look at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations and https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ that will help you give proper configuration directives for various software based on the  security "level" you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left out I was using **Letsencrypt** as certificate provider. I was able to fix the issue and would like to leave this answer up for others who might run into this issue as well.

In my *httpd.conf*, there was

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/virtualhosts-le-ssl.conf
```

Inside my *virtualhosts-le-ssl.conf* was this line:

```
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

I opened that file and it had SSL settings so I can only assume it was indeed overwriting my **SSLCipherSuite** settings. What's baffling is I can use ssl.conf to overwrite my **SSLProtocol** settings but can't do the same with **SSLCipherSuite**.

After changing the SSLCipherSuite inside *virtualhosts-le-ssl.conf*, I was able to successfully modify the Cipher Suite list being shown in ssllabs and have since tweaked it into something more secure.

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Cheers!